# how to print const char pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

Hello I'm trying to print const * char string ended with '\0'

But when I rying to use cout

```
 const char command[9] = {'S', 'T', 'E', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, '\0'}; 
 const char * i = command;
 cout<<i;
```

It give me some squares "[][][]"

So I tried to iterate whole chars

```
     while(*i != '\0'){
         cout << *i;
         i++;
     }
```

It give me : S[][][]. Progress?

When I print *i it give me 'S' but *(i+1) '[][]'.

Is problem with this that I had 8 bit chars, and int is 32 bits?
Or if I doing something wrong?

Solved:

char 13 as a "vertical tab" retur carrage to the start and hide from console "STE", and then C++ print 3 other non printable values.
-Now I need a coffie..

Comment: What do you expect to be printed for `11, 12, 13, 14, 15,`?

Comment: Do you mean for those `int` values to be `string` literals?

Comment: I want to see "STE" not alone "S" rest of them are binary values

Comment: 11-15 are control characters. Some control characters can erase or overwrite previously printed characters.

Comment: @five555 Then change your `while()` condition to [`while(isprint(*i))`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint)

Comment: @five555 You should write an answer for your question instead of editing in _"Solved ..."_

Comment: In ASCII, 11 12 13 14 15 is `<vertical tab> <form feed> <carriage return> <shift out> <shift in>`. Your terminal prints squares for most of those, and the carriage return positions the cursor at the beginning of the line, so you're overwriting "STE".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem

```
const char command[9] = {'S', 'T', 'E', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, '\0'};
```

since the ascii values `11, 12, 13, 14, 15` are not printable characters, try this

```
const char command[14] = {'S', 'T', 'E', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '3', '1', '4', '1', '5', '\0'};
```

[image: Ascii Table]
Image from http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

char 13 as a "vertical tab" retur carrage to the start and hide from console "STE", and then C++ print 3 other non printable values. -Now I need a coffie..

Sorry I stuck with this.

Comment: @iharob because of SO rules I cant accept mine for 2 days